# I am having problems starting Xampp

Tags: xampp

Xampp will not start up, the console pops up saying starting Xampp etc. then disappears. However The Xampp control console does not pop up, when i click on it it says its already running but I cant open it. When I type in local host in IE I get the 404 error message not found. I made sure to give Xampp access to network. Why can't I start up Xampp?

Answer (score 0):

Is 80 port open? Skype use this port by default.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. I basically just uninstalled and reinstalled all works well.

Answer (score 0):

I know may be late .. but i can help you when this prob again arises .
With skype
1. take tools in skype and take connection options.
2. uncheck the "use port number 80"
3. also change use use port for incoming calls to any other.

FOR XAMPP
1. do one thing restart your system 
2. take command prompt .
3. type netstat -ao
4. then you can get the PID  for the port number 80.(remember this PID)
5  take task manager, click on services
6. find the PID which you have found in the command prompt ealier for port number 80
7. right click on it and stop the service.

Now you can take the xampp control panel and run apache and sql.. the issues will be solved.